# Update top n rows of a table in slick

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I want to update top n rows of a table not the entire one when using `slick 3.0`

This is the update all version:

```
private[this] val active = this.filter(a => a.status =!= AccountStatus.DISABLED)
db.run(
    active.filter(a => a.usedBy.isEmpty || a.usedBy === Host.name)
    .map(account => account.usedBy)
    .update("host-a")
)
```

I tried to use this version but it didn't work and thrown an exception

```
private[this] val active = this.filter(a => a.status =!= AccountStatus.DISABLED)
db.run(
    active.filter(a => a.usedBy.isEmpty || a.usedBy === Host.name)
    .take(10)
    .map(account => account.usedBy)
    .update(Option(Host.name))
)
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: slick.SlickException: A query for an UPDATE statement must resolve to a comprehension with a single table -- Unsupported shape: Comprehension s2, Some(Apply Function and), None, ConstArray(), None, None, Some(LiteralNode 100 (volatileHint=false)), None
at slick.driver.JdbcStatementBuilderComponent$QueryBuilder.buildUpdate(JdbcStatementBuilderComponent.scala:447)
at slick.driver.JdbcProfile$$anonfun$updateCompiler$1.apply(JdbcProfile.scala:30)
at slick.driver.JdbcProfile$$anonfun$updateCompiler$1.apply(JdbcProfile.scala:30)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcMappingCompilerComponent$JdbcCodeGen.compileServerSideAndMapping(JdbcMappingCompilerComponent.scala:59)
```

Comment: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1672

Comment: Lesson -> If you can not do something with SQL then you can not do that with Slick .

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh oops, you could do that easily with SQL. Why did you say that?

Answer (score 2):

Well... the answer to this lies in that fact that you are trying to do something which Slick is not supposed to do.

A very simple guideline - When in doubt think in SQL then transform to Slick

Just think how will you achieve this in SQL,

If I transform your "query",

```
// lets say Host.name = "Awesome-Host"

active.filter(a => a.usedBy.isEmpty || a.usedBy === Host.name)
  .take(10)
  .map(account => account.usedBy)
  .update(Option(Host.name))
```

to SQL, it will be something like this,

```
UPDATE
    active
SET
    used_by = 'Awesome-Host'
WHERE
    used_by IS NULL
    OR used_by = 'Awesome-Host'
LIMIT 10
```

Which is kind of absurd from an SQL perspective...

Now... Lets talk about how will you actually do it with SQL,

```
UPDATE
    (
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            active
        WHERE
            used_by IS NULL
            OR used_by = 'Awesome-Host'
        LIMIT 10
    ) active_selection
SET
    active_selection.used_by = 'Awesome-Host'
```

And... this can be translated to Slick using Sub-Queries

```
val activeSelection = active
  .filter(a => a.usedBy.isEmpty || a.usedBy === Host.name)
  .take(10)

val updateSelection = activeSelection
  .map(a => a.usedBy)
  .update(Option(Host.name))
```

Comment: Thanks @Singh, but the first SQL transformation should work with MySQL. I use MySQL. 
But then, I will try the second case to see if it work and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

We recently ran into a similar situation.

The solution was to use a subquery:

```scala
val subquery = myTable.filter(...).take(1)

myTable
  .filter(_.id in subquery.map(_.id))
  .map(row => ...)
  .update(...)
```