# Update Statement with filter, sortBy, map and take

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I am writing the following update statement against a MySql database:

```
Orders.filter(_.cookie === cookie).sortBy(_.id.desc).map(_.payTypeId).take(1)
```

`sortBy` and `take(1)` are being used to ensure I'm only updating the most recent order for a particular cookie. This query works fine as a regular SELECT, this issue here is using it as an update statement.

The error I'm getting:

```
[SlickException: A query for an UPDATE statement must resolve to a comprehension with a single table -- Unsupported shape: Comprehension s2, Some(Apply Function =), None, ConstArray((Path s2.id,Ordering(Desc,NullsDefault))), None, None, Some(LiteralNode 1 (volatileHint=false)), None, false]
```

If I remove the `take(1)` clause, everything works fine. Why I am I getting this error?

Github seems to have a [discussion about this](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1672#issuecomment-307386152), with no solution.

*Workaround using plain SQL*

(This query returns a `Vector[Int]`)

```
        val updateQuery =
      sql"""
         UPDATE
            orders
         SET
          orders.pay_type_id = $id
         WHERE
            orders.cart_cookie = $cookie
         ORDER BY id desc
         LIMIT 1
      """.as[Int]
```

Comment: Have you tried the approach suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41333001/4993128)?

Comment: Yes, but with no luck, (the Github commenter references that answer as well)